# Bootstrap dropdown menu add text fields on menu item click

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is an example of something I am trying to implement:

http://www.bootply.com/60886#

How does one create text forms in the dropdown menu on click. Following the example, how would one move the login (currently in the nav bar) to the dropdown menu and still retain what it does on click (but now display the text boxes and login button in the dropdown menu)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a form like any other element ultimately.

```css
.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu form .form-group .form-control,
.navbar .dropdown-menu form .form-group label,
.navbar .dropdown-menu form .form-group .btn-primary {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li>
              <form action="#">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="username">Username</label>
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" />
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" />
                  <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In" />
                </div>
              </form>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```